# QT and check boxes problem

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qcheckbox

probably what i am asking is very easy, but i'm stuck! :(

i have a `QWidget` in which i load a `QGridLayout` in which i add a number of `QCheckBox`'es

i can't seem to figure out how to catch the changestate signal from the checkboxes....

the check boxes are added in a for loop, in which i create a new QCheckBox
which and adding it as a widget to the qgridlayout...

what am i supposed to connect?
each button's changestate signal to my custom slot, or something else?

the code i use is

```
QGridLayout *myLayout = new QGridLayout;
for (int i=0; i<(int)m_List.size(); i++)
{
    QCheckBox *button = new QCheckBox;
    button->setText(m_List[i].m_strName.c_str());
    button->setIcon(QIcon(m_List[i].m_strThumbNailPath.c_str()));
    button->setIconSize(QSize(50, 50));
    button->setCheckable(true);
    myLayout->addWidget(button);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(stateChanged), this, SLOT(checkboxStateChanged));
}


myLayout->setRowStretch(2, 10);
myLayout->setColumnStretch(2, 10);

QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget;
myWidget->setLayout(myLayout);

myToolbox = new QToolBox;
myToolbox->addItem(myWidget, "Options");
```

it displays the checkboxes correctly, i can check and un-check them, but i can't catch the signal...
what am i missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your connection is problematic (no signature):

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(stateChanged), this, SLOT(checkboxStateChanged));
```

add the parementers to: `stateChanged` and `checkboxStateChanged`

should be something like:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkboxStateChanged(int)));
```

You will get the checkbox state in the `checkboxStateChanged` int parameter as one of

```
Qt::CheckState
```

enum values, see [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#CheckState-enum)

Comment: In fact, OP should probably connect to `SIGNAL(toggled(bool))`. `SIGNAL(stateChanged(int))` is only interesting for tristate checkboxes (used rarely). And yes, [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qcheckbox.html) is a bit misleading here (`toggled(bool)` is defined in `QAbstactButton` instead).

Comment: Well, I just answered his question (-:

Comment: I wish, for every answer using old style signals/slots, some of the more advanced users would go through and re-answer using new style signals and slots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the answer soulSurfer gave probably will fix your connection, but not your problem, there is a bigger fish to fry. How are you going to understand which button was clicked (I assume it matters)?

To understand which button was clicked you will have to use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsignalmapper.html) or [QButtonGroup.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qbuttongroup.html)

Hope this helps.